# Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined with react and vite app

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to use hot reload in my Vite application.
While `vite build` and `vite preview` function properly, I encounter a white screen with an **Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined at publicUtils.jsx:147:37** when I run `vite` (alias npm run dev).

Below is my vite.config.json:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { vanillaExtractPlugin } from "@vanilla-extract/vite-plugin";
import mkcert from "vite-plugin-mkcert";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    vanillaExtractPlugin(),
    mkcert({
      hosts: ["localhost"],
    }),
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["lodash", "react-is", "prop-types"],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      lodash: "lodash-es",
      "react-is": "react-is",
      "prop-types": "prop-types",
    },
  },
  esbuild: {
    jsxInject: import React from 'react',
  },
  server: { https: true, port: 4173, host: "localhost" },
});
```

And here my package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "my-vite-react-ts-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sas/client": "file:./framework/sas-client-1.0.0.tgz",
    "@sas/components": "file:./framework/sas-components-1.0.0.tgz",
    "@sas/ui-client": "file:./framework/sas-ui-client-1.0.0.tgz",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "polished": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-focus-lock": "^2.5.2",
    "react-is": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.172",
    "@types/node": "^20.1.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react-is": "^17.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
    "@vanilla-extract/css": "^1.10.0",
    "@vanilla-extract/css-utils": "^0.1.1",
    "@vanilla-extract/sprinkles": "^1.1.3",
    "@vanilla-extract/vite-plugin": "^3.8.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "typescript": "4.8.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.2",
    "vite-plugin-commonjs-externals": "^0.1.1",
    "vite-plugin-mkcert": "^1.5.0"
  }
}
```

The publicUtils.jsx :

```
let renderErr = 'Renderer Error ☝️'

export const actions = {
  init: 'init',
}

export const defaultRenderer = ({ value = '' }) => value
export const emptyRenderer = () => <>&nbsp;</>

export const defaultColumn = {
  Cell: defaultRenderer,
  width: 150,
  minWidth: 0,
  maxWidth: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
}

function mergeProps(...propList) {
  return propList.reduce((props, next) => {
    const { style, className, ...rest } = next

    props = {
      ...props,
      ...rest,
    }

    if (style) {
      props.style = props.style
        ? { ...(props.style || {}), ...(style || {}) }
        : style
    }

    if (className) {
      props.className = props.className
        ? props.className + ' ' + className
        : className
    }

    if (props.className === '') {
      delete props.className
    }

    return props
  }, {})
}

function handlePropGetter(prevProps, userProps, meta) {
  // Handle a lambda, pass it the previous props
  if (typeof userProps === 'function') {
    return handlePropGetter({}, userProps(prevProps, meta))
  }

  // Handle an array, merge each item as separate props
  if (Array.isArray(userProps)) {
    return mergeProps(prevProps, ...userProps)
  }

  // Handle an object by default, merge the two objects
  return mergeProps(prevProps, userProps)
}

export const makePropGetter = (hooks, meta = {}) => {
  return (userProps = {}) =>
    [...hooks, userProps].reduce(
      (prev, next) =>
        handlePropGetter(prev, next, {
          ...meta,
          userProps,
        }),
      {}
    )
}

export const reduceHooks = (hooks, initial, meta = {}, allowUndefined) =>
  hooks.reduce((prev, next) => {
    const nextValue = next(prev, meta)
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      if (!allowUndefined && typeof nextValue === 'undefined') {
        console.info(next)
        throw new Error(
          'React Table: A reducer hook ☝️ just returned undefined! This is not allowed.'
        )
      }
    }
    return nextValue
  }, initial)

export const loopHooks = (hooks, context, meta = {}) =>
  hooks.forEach(hook => {
    const nextValue = hook(context, meta)
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      if (typeof nextValue !== 'undefined') {
        console.info(hook, nextValue)
        throw new Error(
          'React Table: A loop-type hook ☝️ just returned a value! This is not allowed.'
        )
      }
    }
  })

export function ensurePluginOrder(plugins, befores, pluginName, afters) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && afters) {
    throw new Error(
      `Defining plugins in the "after" section of ensurePluginOrder is no longer supported (see plugin ${pluginName})`
    )
  }
  const pluginIndex = plugins.findIndex(
    plugin => plugin.pluginName === pluginName
  )

  if (pluginIndex === -1) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      throw new Error(`The plugin "${pluginName}" was not found in the plugin list!
This usually means you need to need to name your plugin hook by setting the 'pluginName' property of the hook function, eg:

  ${pluginName}.pluginName = '${pluginName}'
`)
    }
  }

  befores.forEach(before => {
    const beforeIndex = plugins.findIndex(
      plugin => plugin.pluginName === before
    )
    if (beforeIndex > -1 && beforeIndex > pluginIndex) {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        throw new Error(
          `React Table: The ${pluginName} plugin hook must be placed after the ${before} plugin hook!`
        )
      }
    }
  })
}

export function functionalUpdate(updater, old) {
  return typeof updater === 'function' ? updater(old) : updater
}

export function useGetLatest(obj) {
  const ref = React.useRef()
  ref.current = obj

  return React.useCallback(() => ref.current, [])
}

// SSR has issues with useLayoutEffect still, so use useEffect during SSR
export const safeUseLayoutEffect =
  typeof document !== 'undefined' ? React.useLayoutEffect : React.useEffect

export function useMountedLayoutEffect(fn, deps) {
  const mountedRef = React.useRef(false)

  safeUseLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (mountedRef.current) {
      fn()
    }
    mountedRef.current = true
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, deps)
}

export function useAsyncDebounce(defaultFn, defaultWait = 0) {
  const debounceRef = React.useRef({})

  const getDefaultFn = useGetLatest(defaultFn)
  const getDefaultWait = useGetLatest(defaultWait)

  return React.useCallback(
    async (...args) => {
      if (!debounceRef.current.promise) {
        debounceRef.current.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          debounceRef.current.resolve = resolve
          debounceRef.current.reject = reject
        })
      }

      if (debounceRef.current.timeout) {
        clearTimeout(debounceRef.current.timeout)
      }

      debounceRef.current.timeout = setTimeout(async () => {
        delete debounceRef.current.timeout
        try {
          debounceRef.current.resolve(await getDefaultFn()(...args))
        } catch (err) {
          debounceRef.current.reject(err)
        } finally {
          delete debounceRef.current.promise
        }
      }, getDefaultWait())

      return debounceRef.current.promise
    },
    [getDefaultFn, getDefaultWait]
  )
}

export function makeRenderer(instance, column, meta = {}) {
  return (type, userProps = {}) => {
    const Comp = typeof type === 'string' ? column[type] : type

    if (typeof Comp === 'undefined') {
      console.info(column)
      throw new Error(renderErr)
    }

    return flexRender(Comp, { ...instance, column, ...meta, ...userProps })
  }
}

export function flexRender(Comp, props) {
  return isReactComponent(Comp) ? <Comp {...props} /> : Comp
}

function isReactComponent(component) {
  return (
    isClassComponent(component) ||
    typeof component === 'function' ||
    isExoticComponent(component)
  )
}

function isClassComponent(component) {
  return (
    typeof component === 'function' &&
    (() => {
      const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(component)
      return proto.prototype && proto.prototype.isReactComponent
    })()
  )
}

function isExoticComponent(component) {
  return (
    typeof component === 'object' &&
    typeof component.$$typeof === 'symbol' &&
    ['react.memo', 'react.forward_ref'].includes(component.$$typeof.description)
  )
}
```

Please let me know if you require a complete reproduction of the application. Thank you very much.

I did some research but I didn't find something working, it's weird that everything works when I use vite build and vite preview but nothing with vite

Comment: Hi , can you share your publicUtils.jsx file

Comment: I shared the files, as you can see there is no react import but my vite.config.ts should import it, isn't it?

Comment: Hi,  that error meant you are using React like  return React.useCallback(() => ref.current, []) but react is undefined in your publicUtils file, so you have to import react in it, you are using React.memo, or React.callBack from React, but react is undefined hence the refrence error